# Как узнать сколько комбинаций понадобиться что бы передать 1?

Tags: c++, математика

Я хочу сделать подсчет с учетом малой теоремы ферма.
У меня есть два любых числа, которые я могу указать.

Например возьмем `60` и `101`

Теперь зная эти числа, в теории вы можете передать единицу, манипулируя этими числами.

По сколько я знаю ответ, я скажу что получиться.

Вам понадобиться `32` раза умножить на `60`, у вас получиться число `1920` затем вы `19` раз умножить число `101` будет `1919`.

```
1920 - 1919 = 1
```

Это доказывает, что зная два любых числа, вы можете передать человеку самую малую сумму.

Теперь я пытаюсь этот алгоритм реализовать на С++ но не знаю с чего начать.

Я хочу указывать любые числа и получать цифры на сколько нужно умножить число что бы получить единицу, или возможно я захочу получить число 10.
Уверен что это делается в одно строчку, а может и нет.

Comment: Это не оно? http://e-maxx.ru/algo/export_extended_euclid_algorithm

Comment: `зная два любых числа` - не любых, а взаимно простых

Comment: что значит взаимно простых, я бы хотел брать два любых числа.

Comment: Это расширенный алгоритм Евклида как правильно указали. Подходит для любых двух взаимно простых чисел. Если вас интересует решение диофантова уравнения ax+by=1, то оно не  всегда имеет решение. Можно посмотреть на вики.

Comment: Как только для 8 и 16 вы покажете, как получить 1 - так сразу!

Comment: "p — простое число и a — целое число, не делящееся на p" - вырезка из википедии. Малая Теорема Ферма

Comment: хотите сказать что есть числа при котором нельзя получить 1?
Это доказано или это только теория

Comment: Я вам показал такие :) См. также ответ...

Comment: А если одно число простое а другое нет?

Comment: А тогда - если первое число не является делителем второго - они взаимнопростые.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Немножко математики...

Пусть есть числа a и b и у них НОД - d. Тогда

```
a = kd
b = ld
```

И любое выражение

```
ma+nb = (km+ln)d
```

будет кратно d. Так что *любое* значение вы получите только для взаимно простых чисел... А для не взаимнопростых - кратное их НОД.

Использовав для этого расширенный алгоритм Евклида.

Привожу его [реализацию](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/export_extended_euclid_algorithm)

```
int gcd (int a, int b, int & x, int & y)
{
    if (a == 0) {
        x = 0; y = 1;
        return b;
    }
    int x1, y1;
    int d = gcd (b%a, a, x1, y1);
    x = y1 - (b / a) * x1;
    y = x1;
    return d;
}
```

Comment: Такое чувство что меня развели, я думал из любого числа можно получить 1
А не только из простых.

Comment: Из любых **взаимно простых**. Например, из 12 и 25. Оба - составные, но 25-2*12=1. **Простые** и **взаимно простые** - это разные вещи.

Comment: Спасибо теперь вроде начинаю понимать.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста :)